# Check if value actually changed in WPF property setter?

Tags: .net, wpf

In WPF, is it a best practice to check if the value of a model's property will actually be changed in a property setter, before calling NotifyPropertyChanged?

For example:

```
    private string foobar;

    public string Foobar
    {
        get
        {
            return this.foobar;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value != this.foobar)
            {
                this.foobar = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Foobar");
            }
        }
    }
```

The alternative is to not check and just call NotifyPropertyChanged every time:

```
    private string foobar;

    public string Foobar
    {
        get
        {
            return this.foobar;
        }

        set
        {
            this.foobar = value;
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Foobar");
        }
    }
```

I've seen both styles used in code samples. What, if any, are the advantages and disadvantages of each approach?

Comment: I've just seen that the same question has already been asked:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623697/should-a-setter-return-immediately-if-assigned-the-same-value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I always do the check because the event seems to imply that an actual change should have happened.

(Also it prevents unnecessary updates)